# Can class depending on other class be packed separately in two different jar

Tags: java, jar, runtime, classpath, buildpath

Here is the scenario
Let say I have a class A.java which is dependent on class B.java.

```
public Class A{
  public B b=new B();
}
public Class B{
  //Some business logic...
}
```

And there is application X which uses only class A(somewhere inside X there is `new A()` ). So 
1) can I create 2 jars, one which contain A.class and another jar which contain B.class, add these 2 jars in application ?
2) can I create a one jar which contain only A.class add that jar in application and provide B.class to application on run-time (lets assuming, its possible to inject B.class on runtime)

Note:Adding these 2 classes in single jar is not an option


so as I understand,Class A is compile time dependency of application X and Class B is runtime dependency, correct ?


In point 1 and 2, When I am saying "add jar in application", what exactly I am doing, am I adding those jar in buildpath or classpath of application X ? probably someone can help me in understanding the difference between these "paths", I always gets confused.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to first compile, on your project's buildpath, then provide those classes *again* on the classpath at runtime. You can have the classes together, put them into different jars, and then reunite them at runtime on the classpath.

Comment: Can you elaborate "you need to first compile, on your project's buildpath"

Comment: @Monk789 The buildpath is the set of jars needed at compile time. You provide a set of compiled and uncompiled classes/interfaces/enums and obtain a set of compiled jars and class files. These compiled files go their separate ways but must reuinite again when running the application, even if `A` and `B` are in different jars, as long as they are on the runtime classparg.